# Protect youtube link

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, youtube, video.js

I am using video-js in combination with its youtube plugin on my website. Video content on this website is premium and only first X users should be able to view it. Right now its being realised by passing a YouTube link that is unlisted (cant be searched on YouTube and can be accessed via direct link only) into my website and afterwards first X users with specific link to my website can view it.

Logic behind this process lies in fact that these videos can be accessed only through my website so I need to protect YouTube URL from being copied from the JS and HTML.

So I want to ask if there is some way how to dynamicaly obfuscate, encrypt etc. these values/variables that hold URLs so the common user could not steal it?

I say common user because it is clear that the video content is being downloaded into client side so there is no ultimate way on how to protect it from stealing and advanced users can definetly do it but what I mainly want to accomplish is to disable access to the unlisted YouTube URL in the source so the video can be only seen through my website.

P.S. What I know to this point right now - Vimeo provides solution called domain level privacy that provides ability to play videos only on the specific domain what could possibly solve my problem, however my target group are YouTubers so this is not the way I want to go...

Comment: I think it's still possible to get the youtube link after the url is obfuscated, because you can click in the title or right click on the youtube video to get the URL.

Comment: @C0dekid.php in video-js its possible to disable these functionalities, which Ive already done so this is not the problem for me.